# Infinite page_load loop after OnTextChanged()

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, postback, pageload

I have an aspx page with a calendar picker and asp textbox that when the text changes (user picks a calendar date) that it fires off into my code behind. This all works and my dropdown list populates except the fact that it hits my aspx page_load, then my global aspx_pageload then my function infinitely.

My html

```
   <tr>
            <td class="InfoLabel">Date of Survey</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="dateOfSurvey" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="getAvailableTimes"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="InfoLabel">Time of Survey</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="timeOfSurvey" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

My aspx page_load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            using (var connectionString = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connectionString.Open();

                    ListItemCollection collection = new ListItemCollection();
                    collection.Add(new ListItem(""));
                    timeOfSurvey.DataSource = collection;
                    timeOfSurvey.DataBind();

                    connectionString.Close();
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My function only populates a DDL

```
    protected void getAvailableTimes(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    ListItemCollection collection = new ListItemCollection();
                    collection.Add(new ListItem(""));
                    collection.Add(new ListItem("08:30:00"));
                    collection.Add(new ListItem("13:00:00"));
                    timeOfSurvey.DataSource = collection;
                    timeOfSurvey.DataBind();
    }
```

And finally my global aspx is just a blank page_load

How can I break or fix the cycle of this infinite loop? My page does what I want it  to do except after its done it infinitely loops back through the cycle mentioned above.

Comment: `How can I break or fix the cycle of this infinite loop?` What makes you think it is going into an infinite loop? If you use Dev Tools in Chrome, is there a Network request for every iteration?

Comment: @mjwills yes it sends a request every time. I also know its looping because it hits my breakpoints infinitely, disabling breakpoints makes my page reload  like a strobe light.

Comment: That isn't an infinite loop then. That is 'there are lots of web requests and I don't understand why'. Do you know what is triggering those multiple web requests?

Comment: @mjwills Its just repeating the same request over and over after my date is changed on the html side. Default.aspx is starting and also in the request later again.

Comment: @mjwills The issue was my calendar refiring my page load. Thank you for your efforts and informing me about web requests in chrome.